# Bizspark Azure - How to enable load balancer to see instance from multiple accounts

Tags: load-balancing, virtual-machines, azure

We have recently gained access to bizspark and want to create a load balancer which would use instances from all 5 accounts. I’ve tried several approaches, but could not figure out how to get the load balancer to see other instances from other accounts. Is there any easy way that I missing to obtaining this? Ideally, we would want to serve apache from more one than instances.

I want to load balance a web app on multiple accounts - under the same subscription. It can really be any solution as long as I can run the project under apache and have a single endpoint to the traffic.

See https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark

Comment: I am somewhat confused when you say "accounts", what do you mean by accounts? Load balancers will only work with virtual machines in the same subscription and in the same virtual network.

Comment: "Startups, your journey starts in the cloud
BizSpark gives startups 3 years of free stuff – software, services, tech support, and Azure cloud. Your startup qualifies if it is less than 5 years old, is privately held, and earns less than $1M annually. And at the end of your 3 years, you keep all the software you've downloaded – at no cost.
logo cloud
Get up to $750 per month of FREE Azure cloud services for 3 years; that's $150 per month each for up to 5 developers." --> https://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/#build-one --- It's 5 accounts for 5 devs that we have under the same subscription

Comment: Are they actually under the same sub, or 5 separate subs? Billing is done at the sub level so there would be no way to split it by user, it would be one sub with a $750 limit and 5 users, or 5 subs with $150 limit. If it's one sub then you can do it, if it's 5 separate subs then you can't